# how do i create a dynamic field in beaver builder?

Tags: wordpress, web, plugins, elementor

I want to create a dynamic field using the Pods plugin. When a profession is selected in the post type, it should be displayed in a grid.

The problem is that everything is managed with the Beaver Builder. Does anyone know how to add a relationship field there? Unfortunately, I can't find a suitable description.

I have already watched many videos but could not find a solution.
I am looking for a description of how pods and braver builder work together.